# Django templating; queryset empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of countries, they all have there own url [www.example.com/al/](http://www.example.com/al/) for example. There is a list of cities for every country but the object_list is empty

My View:

```
class CityOverview(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'shisha/pages/country_index.html'
    model = City

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        country_id = self.kwargs.get('country_id')
        return City.objects.filter(country__name=country_id)
```

My Model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
        ('al', 'Albania'),
        ('ad', 'Andorra'),
        #etc. etc.
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, default='nl')

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

My Urls:

```
path('<str:country_id>', views.CityOverview.as_view(), name='country'),
```

My Template:

```
{% for city in object_list %}
{{ city.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This returns nothing and when i do

```
{{ object_list }}
```

It returns this

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You did a typo mistake. change this

```
 return City.objects.filter(country__name=country_id)
```

to

```
 return City.objects.filter(country__id=int(country_id))
```

Comment: This is not typo, he is getting short Country name from URL, in Country model it's stored in name choices.

Comment: you can type cast to int. I updated my answer.

Comment: can you please confirm the value of your `country_id` ? your url seems like `<str:country_id>` so you are adding a variable of country_id, this is suppose to an pk of Country Model field from look or what @SergeyPugach just said it is countey_name ?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean? @Shakil

Comment: what is the value of your country_id ? naming like this means that its a country_id or country model pk number. Or this is country_name ( short ) what just sergey said.

Comment: The value of my country_id is the country_name (short) just like sergey said